# Tensorflow - How to train a model if I have limited data?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am a newbie in Tensorflow Object Detection.
I wonder how to train a model detect a part of book (sometime text, sometime image) if I have limit data (image, ex: 1 paper of a book)?
I've tried to train with 1 paper but loss never go down below 1.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

to train a model to detect a part of the book (like it's banner/title) you should make a video of it, extract images using ffmpeg and feed it to the network. Also, you should do some basic courses in ML. When training a model, the dataset should be typically 10k+. The less the input- worse the output. To get the no. of images required, I reccomend u go with ffmpeg.....

Comment: ready made Neural Networks also help in training and fixing the 'noob' errors. I recommend you use Google's AutoML:===>  
 https://cloud.google.com/automl/

Comment: I want to use the model offline. So possible to train model with Tensorflow object detection API by that way? I read few sample and they just use ~100 image for 1 class and it works.

Comment: Yeah , but with less accuracy...(like 85%). Even as a newbie, my own models could bump it up to 94%.....

Answer (score 1):

Best approach would be to augment data which will boost the number of different images you will use to train your model.

Please refer to **openCV** and **scikit-image** for different image transformations techniques like:

- **Affine transformations**
- **Perspective transformations**